Azure Functions in C# .NET version 8 run locally but after the deploy to the Azure and try run it returned Error Could not load file or assembly
I'm in trouble with a simple Azure Function.
I run it locally without problem, but after deploy to Azure the Function do not run and insights show:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

But the project .csproj is:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>azure_function</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Devices" Version="1.39.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
    <!-- Here -->
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.4" />

  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And the local.settings.json is:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}

The Azure Function App is set:

And App environment set to:

Do someone know how I can solve this problem?
All material that I found in web related this type of problem when the function was created in .NET 6 and migrated to .NET 8, but it is not this case here.
Thanks.

When you re-deploy your project, exactly what files are in the web-space?

Possible duplicate of .NET 8 Azure function throws error when using System.Text.Json

What type of trigger you are using? Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker package is used in isolated function but you have added it in inprocess function

It looks like in-process Azure Function Model requires the package System.Text.Json 6.0 version as per this github issue  but this version can't be used in .NET8 in-process function, you need to use 8.0 version or above.
So, you can use System.Text.Json in .NET6 in-process function model or else use Newtonsoft.Json in .NET8 in-process function model.
If you are comfortable to move to isolated function model then System.Text.Json package works perfectly fine for .NET8 isolated model.
I have created an isolated function model with given code in it.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(requestBody);

            string name = null;
            if (data.TryGetProperty("name", out JsonElement nameElement))
            {
                name = nameElement.GetString();
            }

            return new OkObjectResult($"Welcome to Azure Functions, {name}!");
        }
    }
}

.csproj -
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

It works locally as well as in function app.

